# Image Not Resizing w/ Browser (CSS/HTML only)

Tags: html, css, responsive-images

On my current project, all I want is to use CSS/HTML only to get my image, within a , to resize with the page.  I had this working on a previous site and now...it just isn't.  When the browser window is resized, it just cuts off the image, from the right side; no resizing whatsoever.

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

div.divBannerScale {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}

img.bannerScale {
  max-width: 100%;
  min-width: 40%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Website</title>
<link href="/css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>

<div id="bannerDIVcontainer" class="divBannerScale">
 <img src="Images/bannerFull-01.png" width="2561" height="445" class="bannerScale" />
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I've tried adding `margin: 0 auto`, `display: block`, `padding`, etc on each the `div` class and the `image` class but ultimately removed them since it didn't seem to make a difference. (And wasn't needed in the past.)

I really don't understand why it's not working now when it was on the other, much messier-coded site.  I'm not an expert, clearly, but usually I can figure these things out.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: works fine for me :/

Comment: Remove the inline styling of image ` width="2561" height="445"`

Comment: Setting `width` and `height` attribute of `img` tag is causing the problem. Remove it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps your image is already 40% of its original size? In my testing, the code seemed to work fine.

Trimming out all redundant the CSS just leaves (if the min width was indeed too big):

```
img.bannerScale {
  max-width: 100%;
  min-width: 1%;
  height: auto;
}
```

You can see a live example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/51zyc4qk/).

Note that that you don't need to do anything to the div size as it will just be as big as whatever you put in it (assuming you're not doing anything funky such as absolute positioning)

Comment: Thank you for the assistance :)
After you and a few others said it was essentially fine, I decided to keep working on some other things and discovered that the stylesheet wasn't being referenced in my previews/testing.